# How to get data from store / react redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, frontend

```
 const initialState = {
   id: null,
   username: "",
   email: "",
   avatar_url: "",
   userLoad_error: false,
   error_message: "",
 };
 Slice
 const user = createSlice({
   name: "user",
   initialState,
   reducers: {
     UserLoadData(state, action) {
       state.id = action.payload.id;
       state.username = action.payload.username;
       state.email = action.payload.email;
       state.avatar_url = action.payload.avatar_url;
     },
     UserFaildLoadData(state, action) {
       state.userLoad_error = action.payload.error;
       state.error_message = action.payload.error_message;
     },
   },
 });
 Api
 const { UserLoadData, UserFaildLoadData } = user.actions;
 export function UserLoad() {
   return async (dispatch) => {
     try {
       const response = await API.get("/user");
       const data = response.data;
 
       const id = data.data.id;
       const username = data.data.username;
       const email = data.data.email;
       const avatar_url = data.data.avatar.url;
 
       dispatch(
         UserLoadData({
           id: id,
           username: username,
           email: email,
           avatar_url: avatar_url
         })
       );
     } catch (e) {
       const error = e.response;
       let error_message = null;
 
       if (error) {
         if (error.status === 401) error_message = "Wrong data!";
       } else error_message = "No connection to the server!";
       dispatch(
         UserFaildLoadData({
           login_error: true,
           error_message,
         })
       );
     }
   };
 }
 
 FrontEnd
     const dispatch = useDispatch();
     useEffect(() => {
         dispatch(UserLoad())
     }, [])
```

React-Redux-Store.
How to use data from store, im beginner in react and redux, so i even dont understand how to get data after dispatch and where its store.

> /sometextsometextsometextsometextsometextsometextsometextsometextsometextsometextsometextsometextsometextsometextsometextsometextsometextsometextsometextsometextsometextsometextsometextsometextsometextsometextsometextsometextsometextsometextsometextsometextsometextsometextsometextsometextsometextsometextsometextsometextsometextsometextsometextsometextsometextsometextsometextsometextsometextsometextsometextsometextsometextsometextsometextsometextsometextsometextsometextsometextsometextsometextsometextsometextsometextsometextsometextsometextsometext/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would use the [`useSelector`](https://react-redux.js.org/tutorials/quick-start#use-redux-state-and-actions-in-react-components) hook for that. But honestly, this looks like you are taking the tenths step before the first step here, because figuring out how your components interact with Redux should come a long time *before* you write asynchronous data fetching logic.

I would highly recommend that you follow the [official Redux tutorial](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-1-overview-concepts) **from the beginning**.